# How to remove the extra column in DevExpress GridControl using WPF?

Tags: devexpress, wpf-4.0, gridcontrol

Basically my requirement is to remove the extra column in `DevExpress` `GridControl` using `WPF`. I have a `GridControl` which contains three columns, while the `GridControl` shows three columns perfectly the rest of `GridContol` area is shows as an **extra column**. I want to remove that extra column, so is there any solution?

[image]
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [TableView.AutoWidth](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridTableView_AutoWidthtopic) property:

```
<dxg:GridControl>
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="ID"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Name"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Age"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView AutoWidth="True"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Related help-article: [Columns Layout and Width](http://help.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6296)

Comment: It will work but I got a new problem it will set the ContentAlignment in right align.

Comment: @EzraHeywood alignment issue screenshot??

Comment: @EzraHeywood Happy to hear that the problem is now resolved. Please always accept the answer if this answer is correct or share us with an alternative helpful solution.